# Get the proper ordering or results from mysql query

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm using C#.

I'm trying to run a query to get the last 20 results in the database, but it returns them like this right now and says the last entry is number "1211".

```
1211
1210
1209 .. etc
```

If the last entry is "1211" I need it to start at "1191" and increment up!

I'm using this right now:

```
string query = string.Format("
    SELECT mesgnumber, targetid, targettype, data, timestamp, sendingid, contenttype
    FROM history
    WHERE targetid='{0}'
    AND targettype='{1}'
    ORDER BY mesgnumber DESC
    LIMIT 20",
    target, IsGroupToInt);
```

I have tried numerous methods, to no avail. I thought the following would work, yet it didn't:

```
string query = string.Format("
    SELECT mesgnumber, targetid, targettype, data, timestamp, sendingid, contenttype
    FROM history
    WHERE targetid='{0}'
    AND targettype='{1}'
    ORDER BY mesgnumber DESC
    LIMIT 20,
    mesgnumber ASC", target, IsGroupToInt);
```

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order in one direction in a subquery, then reverse the order in the main query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ... ORDER BY mesgnumber DESC LIMIT 20) AS subquery
ORDER BY mesgnumber ASC
```

Comment: Thanks You..! @Barmar

Comment: If it solved your problem, click the check mark next to the question to accept the solution.